# jQuery dataTable AJAX population

Tags: jquery, datatable

So the table is on the page

```
<table width="100%" id="ticketListTable" class="genmed"></table>
```

I then use AJAX to return the data

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "ticketAjax.php",
    data: '&m=swapTicketList',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(resultData) {
        $('#ticketListTable').dataTable({
            "aaData": resultData,
            "aaSorting": [[0, "desc"]],
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bScrollInfinite": true,
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
            "bDestroy": true,
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 100,
            "sScrollY": "1000px",
            "sDom": "Rlfrtip",
        });
    }
});
```

The AJAX is working and returning

```
[{"ID":["17316","17314","17313","17312","17311","17310","17309","17308","17307"....
```

However aaData is not populating the table with that Json data. Am i misunderstanding how this works? I have read quite a few forums and posts and they all appear to lead to this type of usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it wasn't as easy as i thought. In the AJAX i had to build the array, then return it with json_encode inside another array.

```
json_encode(array('tickets' => $tickets)) //-- WHERE $tickets = array(array(1, 'Options 1'), array(2, 'Options 2'))
```

I also had to return the column headers as an array

```
json_encode(array('tickets' => $tickets, 'headers' => $headers)) //-- WHERE $headers = array('ID', 'Options', etc..)
```

The amount of elements in $headers has to match $tickets or it will not initialize the table.

Then the JS part for the headers was

```
            aoColumnArray = [];
        $.each(resultData.headers, function(index, value) {
            var aoColumns = new Object;
            aoColumns['sTitle'] = value;
            aoColumns['sClass'] = 'genmed';
            aoColumnArray.push(aoColumns);
        });
```

Now build the datatable object

```
            ticketTable= [];
        ticketTable.aaData = resultData.tickets;
        ticketTable.aaSorting = [[0, "asc"], [1, "desc"], [2, "desc"]];
        ticketTable.aoColumns = aoColumnArray;
        ticketTable.bJQueryUI = true;
        ticketTable.bScrollInfinite = true;
        ticketTable.bScrollCollapse = true;
        ticketTable.bDestroy = true;
        ticketTable.bDeferRender = true;
        ticketTable.iDisplayLength = 50;
        ticketTable.sScrollY = '400px';
        ticketTable.sDom = 'Rlfrtip';
        $('#ticketTable').dataTable(ticketTable);
```

Use the options you want to use. The important part is the resultData being handled. aaData & aoColumns are where the AJAX'ed data is used. All of this is initialized in the success function of the ajax call by the way.

Hopefully it will help someone else!

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide an array of arrays for data, not objects. Also define your columns. Sub arrays will represent individual rows, main array wraps all rows

Follow the `JS Array` example

http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Note nested array structure provided to `aaData` and follow that structure

Comment: If that where the case, why is [{"sTitle":"ID","sClass":"genmed"},{"sTitle":"Options","sClass":"genmed"},{"sTitle":"Created","sClass":"genmed"},{"sTitle":"Status","sClass":"genmed"}] not populating the columns?

Comment: I figured it all out an added it to the post for others, thanks for taking the time to help!